# how to send CTR+I sequence in VT100 / putty

Tags: putty, vt100

I have access to the remote server via serial console with VT100.
I need to change some settings which are available during boot after pressing CTR+I.

Is there a way I can send this key combination via serial console using putty.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is control/I (9th letter), which is the same as the tab character, in ASCII (used by VT100).